# Collecting data locally on the iPad for retrieval later

Tags: javascript, ipad, html

This isn't a native iPad app. This is a HTML5 web app which runs from the iPad's local storage (so it will display offline).

What I need to do is have a form which collects information and stores it somewhere locally for retrieval later.

Is there any way I can achieve this. I don't care how the data is stored, just that it doesn't expire (like cookies do) and its relatively easy to retrieve at a later date.

Thanks

Comment: Would downvoter like to comment at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple have a [Safari Client-Side Storage and Offline Applications Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SafariJSDatabaseGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) section in their documentation. It lists the various options.

[Key-Value storage](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SafariJSDatabaseGuide/Name-ValueStorage/Name-ValueStorage.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007256-CH6-SW3) sounds like it best fits your usecase.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care what you use, you can just as easily use cookies and set their expiration date to the year 3000 or something!

Alternatively you can take advantage of [localStorage](http://html5doctor.com/storing-data-the-simple-html5-way-and-a-few-tricks-you-might-not-have-known/) and store the form data in JSON format.

Comment: Fair enough, I didn't think cookies would be all that useful, but I guess that you're right. :)